# codeigniter get db object result value into variable in a single command

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to get the value of a codeigniter db result object single value into a variable with 1 command?

I've been doing this:

```
$course_progress_object = this->training_model->get_course_progress($course_id,$user_id);
$course_progress = $course_progress_object[0]->progress;
```

Can we do it in a single command?

get_course_progress

```
public function get_course_progress($course_id, $user_id) {
    $this->db->select('progress');
    $course_object = $this->db->get_where('training_stats', array('course_id =' => $course_id, 'user_id ' => $user_id));
    return $course_object->result();
}
```

I cant find out and tried many things?

Comment: Did you try `$course_progress = this->training_model->get_course_progress($course_id,$user_id)[0]->progress;` ? (Really not sure about this one x) )

Comment: paste code of `get_course_progress` function

Comment: Add model method above

Comment: pls always be responsive to the answers given , mark it with green check and do upvote if you find it helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

**In Model:**

```
public function get_course_progress($course_id, $user_id) 
{
    $this->db->select('progress');
    $course_object = $this->db->get_where('training_stats', array('course_id =' => $course_id, 'user_id ' => $user_id));
    $row = $course_object->row();
    return $row;
}
```

**In Controller:**

```
 $course_progress_object = $this->training_model->get_course_progress($course_id,$user_id);
 $course_progress = $course_progress_object->progress;
```